# Add link to dynamic text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I'm trying to make a dynamic text a link with javascript:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="form-current">
  <form>
    <h2 style="margin-left:10px" ><a href='#' onclick="homePage()" id="h2Current" ></a></h2>
    <div id="node-current"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is the html and the text is loaded from a DB through a javascript function:

```
var h2Current = document.getElementById('h2Current');
h2Current.innerHTML = 'Day '+data[0]['day'];
```

the parameter "data" is a simple Json. The text appear underlined correctly but is impossibile to click.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON? And is that *all* the JavaScript you're using to append the new HTML (from the JSON) to the page?

Comment: Where is the function homePage defined?

Comment: function homePage(){
      window.location="client.html?user="+user;
    }
is a simple function and is defined in the html page

Comment: You edit the innerHTML of <h2> to `day xyz` instead of `<a ...>`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @David: This is the code for append the text to the html page

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the JSON since you say that it appears and is underlined properly. The issue is that you are either not actually calling your 'homePage' function during the 'onclick' event, or there is an unhandled exception in the code of your 'homePage' function. Here is how you go about debugging this issue.

You need to open your site in Chrome, and open the developer tools, 'F12'. Click the 'Sources' tab, and find your .JS file, or the page file, if it contains the function, 'homePage' inline. You may need to open the 'File Navigator'.  If this is the case, click the "arrow in the box" directly beneath the 'Elements' tab.

Once the file is opened, find the function declaration 'homePage' and breakpoint the first non var declarative line. Now, simply click the link and step through the function.  You may find that you are not even calling the function at all and you may even see JS exceptions listed. Address any exceptions which appear inline in your code.  If you are actually reaching your function, step through every line, 'F11' including any nested functions, until you find the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your JSON. Check JSON i have written is a correct one. check your JSON format. You can use jsonlint.com to validate JSON you are trying to use.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="form-current">
  <form>
    <h2 style="margin-left:10px" ><a href='#' onclick="homePage()" id="h2Current" ></a></h2>
    <div id="node-current"></div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var data =  [{ 'day':'monday'},{ 'day':'tuesday'}]

var h2Current = document.getElementById('h2Current');
h2Current.innerHTML = data[0]['day'];
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the Json is correct, I use it in different ways in the page. I simply can't make it a link and I don't know why.

Comment: I've found the problem:

The div containing the form was under to another div. I've added a z-index to the div and all is gone well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good that you got the answer.